# Camera is not returing back me captured image

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I'm working on an android app that produces effects in images. I want the users of my app to have two options.

1) They can choose pictures from Gallery

2) They can capture a new photo from camera

Here is how I'm accomplishing the aforementioned two tasks:

```
Button takePhotoFromCameraButton;
Button chooseFromGalleryButton;


String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_image.jpg";
File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
```

In both buttons, I'm passing the same onClickListner.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View clickedView) {

    int clickedViewId = clickedView.getId();

    switch(clickedViewId) {
        case R.id.takeFromCamera:
            Intent imageCaptureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            imageCaptureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(imageCaptureIntent,0);
            break;
        case R.id.chooseFromGallery:
            Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 1);
            break;
        default:
            // As we have only two buttons, and nothing else can be clicked except the buttons. So no need to put
            // code in the "DEFAULT CASE"
    }
}
```

And I'm capturing the result from both, the following way:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MainOptionsActivity.this,ApplyEffectsActivity.class);
            cameraIntent.putExtra("imageFileUri", imageUri);
            startActivity(cameraIntent);
            break;
        case 1:
            Uri imageUriForGallery = intent.getData();
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(MainOptionsActivity.this,ApplyEffectsActivity.class);
            galleryIntent.putExtra("imageFileUri", imageUriForGallery);
            startActivity(galleryIntent);
            break;
    }

}
```

}

The button for gallery images works fine. But when I invoke camera by pressing the second button and capture the image, nothing happens. It stays there till I cancel the camera and come back to my app. I don't receive any image back!
Where I'm wrong? Don't mind this silly question, I'm just a beginner in android! :(

Comment: Not helping... I'm using one onActivityResult method for two views, whereas the link you wrote, not does so.

Comment: What happens? Is onActivityResult never called or is it called with wrong values?

Comment: Why are you starting the activity in onActivityResult..? if you want to receive the image you need to do  Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  like this..

Comment: @Jackopo Camera is launched, I take picture and press the Yes option then it doesn't take me back to my app. I stuck there until I hit the cancel button on Camera.

Comment: @Pragnani Yes, I'm calling startActivity() in onActivityResult() to launch another activity that actually puts effects in images.
You are right, but actually I want to obtain the Uri of image, and pass it to the next activity for modification purposes.

Comment: @ArslanAli That is good but where are you receiving the image data from the intent..?

Comment: @ArslanAli you need to call this in your first case also   Uri imageUriForGallery = intent.getData();

Comment: @Pragnani I edited my question. Now, you should know what **imageFileUri** is coming from and what my intentions are! :)

Comment: @ArslanAli your code seems to be correct, is there any exception in the logcat..?

Comment: @Pragnani Oppppsss! Yap there is! 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo { 
who=null, ..... I hope you get it!

Comment: it seems your intent.getData() returning null, try to add  this condition if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){..}

Comment: @Pragnani Finally got it!

`String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_image.jpg";`
I wasn't putting "/" in it! Silly mistake, took me 4 hours to find it! Thanks bro for your help too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I implemented mine, I made it work this way through a fragment:

```
public class ConcertFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

ImageView toto;
ToggleButton btnFlashlight;
RayMenu menu;
View rootView;

private Camera cam;
boolean hasCamera;
Parameters params;
private int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE;
Bitmap photo;
Uri imageUri;

public ConcertFragment() {
}

public void startCameraIntent() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SurfaceView preview = (SurfaceView)getView().findViewById(R.id.background);
    SurfaceHolder mHolder = preview.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.concert, menu);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getCamera();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_concert, container, false); 
    toto = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toto);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode != 0)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            toto.setImageBitmap(photo);

            View content = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toto);
            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                try {
                    cachePath.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(cachePath));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));
        }
        else {
            cam.release();
        }
    }
}    

// Get the camera
   private void getCamera() {
        if (cam != null) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open();
                params = cam.getParameters();
                cam.startPreview();
                hasCamera = true;

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
                cam.release();
            }
        }
   }
```

Hope this helps :) Just ask if you need more information.

**How to do it with an activity, instead of fragment**

```
public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can't use fragments. Have to do it through `Activiy`.