# How to know the intent ACTION_PICK came up with nothing

Tags: android, android-intent

The following code launches the gallery to choose an image from:

```
Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 1);
```

Now, my question is how can I know in `onResultActivity()` method that the intent came back with nothing selected? (i.e The user didn't select any image from the gallery and just hit the cancel button)

I'm using the following code but it isn't helping me accomplish the task!

```
Uri imageUriForGallery = intent.getData();
if(imageUriForGallery == null || imageUriForGallery.toString() == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You didn't choose an image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
}
```

When user doesn't select an image from the gallery and simply hits the cancel button on gallery, my app crashes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, my question is how can I know in `onResultActivity()` method that the intent came back with nothing selected?

Your [`onActivityResult()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) will be called [with `RESULT_CANCELED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_CANCELED) in the second parameter.

Comment: Thankyou very much! It will be pleasure if you solve this problem too

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589299/camera-is-not-returing-back-me-captured-image)